# How do tensors work in a full subcategory of modules over a ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, tensor-products, abelian-categories

I have a ring $A$ (specifically a valuating ring) with a non-trivial ideal $I$. I have shown that we can identify $\text{Mod}_{A/I}$ with the strictly full additive subcategory $\mathcal{C}$ of $\text{Mod}_A$ consisting of those $A$-modules $M$ with $IM=0$.

Is there a quick and easy way to see that translating between taking tensors over $A/I$ and over $A$ works exactly as one would hope? In other words, that if $M$ and $N$ are objects in $\mathcal{C}$, then $M\otimes_A N=M\otimes_{A/I}N$ and the same for tensoring morphisms.

Comment: Yes, just verify that they have the same universal property.

Comment: What is $P{}{}$?

Comment: If $IM=0$ and $IN=0$, then $M\cong M\otimes_{A/I}A/I$ and $N\cong A/I\otimes_AN$ naturally and canonically as $A$-modules, so $M\otimes_AN\cong M\otimes_{A/I}A/I\otimes_A N\cong M\otimes_{A/I}N$ just as naturally and canonically. The «naturally» part is the claim about morphisms.